# Android How to tell if Internet connection is being used?

Tags: android, user-experience

My app download a lot of content (json and image) from the server as the user navigate through the app. For the sake of user experience, instead of downloading the content on the spot, I would like to precache them on memory and SD card so that they can be available without too much waiting.

Since I do not want the precacheing process take up too much network traffic so that the user operation is hindered by the network traffic jam, I would only let the app start precacheing these content when there are not any Internet activity from my app.

Therefore, I would like to ask if there are any way to determine whether there are any internet activity from my app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The user's experience of not being about to use the app when it is first opened because there are other downloads sounds like it would hinder a user. Warning the user about the amount of data could be another solution. At the warning screen (On first open) the user could be directed into the settings where they could setup the network. This allows the user to customize if needed, otherwise they continue with a smooth transition into the app.

The network settings could be setup with ConnectivityManager. This would allow you to see if the user is on Wifi vs mobile data.

http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

The DDMS tool includes a tool for monitoring network traffic. This could be an option.

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html